# How to show "out of stock" child products for configurable product in list and product view page magento 2?

Tags: magento2, out-of-stock, stock-status, cataloginventory, associated-products

I am trying to show out of stock child products for configurable product in details and product view.I changed the settings from catalog inventory to display out of stock products even it is not showing.
 I tried below code but not working.

> Data.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Firstmodule\Helper;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product;

class Data extends \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Helper\Data
{

    protected $imageHelper;
    protected $_productloader;  
    protected $stockRegistry;  
    protected $_storeManager;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image $imageHelper,
        \Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface $stockRegistry,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $_productloader,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
        )
    {
        $this->imageHelper = $imageHelper;
        $this->stockRegistry = $stockRegistry;
        $this->_productloader = $_productloader;
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        parent::__construct($imageHelper);
    }


     public function getOptions($currentProduct, $allowedProducts)
    {
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
       // $stockRegistry = $objectManager->get('Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface');
        $options = [];
        foreach ($allowedProducts as $product) {
            $productId = $product->getId();
            $product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($productId);
            $stockitem = $this->stockRegistry->getStockItem($product->getId(), $product->getStore()->getWebsiteId());
            if($stockitem->getQty() == 0) continue;
            $images = $this->getGalleryImages($product);
            if ($images) {
                foreach ($images as $image) {
                    $options['images'][$productId][] =
                        [
                            'thumb' => $image->getData('small_image_url'),
                            'img' => $image->getData('medium_image_url'),
                            'full' => $image->getData('large_image_url'),
                            'caption' => $image->getLabel(),
                            'position' => $image->getPosition(),
                            'isMain' => $image->getFile() == $product->getImage(),
                        ];
                }
            }
            foreach ($this->getAllowAttributes($currentProduct) as $attribute) {
                $productAttribute = $attribute->getProductAttribute();
                $productAttributeId = $productAttribute->getId();
                $attributeValue = $product->getData($productAttribute->getAttributeCode());
                $options[$productAttributeId][$attributeValue][] = $productId;
                $options['index'][$productId][$productAttributeId] = $attributeValue;
            }
        }
        return $options;
    }


}
```

> di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">


    <preference for="Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Helper\Data" type="Vendor\Firstmodule\Helper\Data" />

</config>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change this line

`$stockitem = $this->stockRegistry->getStockItem($product->getId(), $product->getStore()->getWebsiteId());`

TO

`$stockitem = $this->stockRegistry->get($product->getId(), $product->getStore()->getWebsiteId());
echo 'Stock : '.$stockitem->getIsInStock();`

$_productStock->getIsInStock() return 0 or 1 value 
based on this put lable 'in-stock' or 'out-stock'

use this repository

`\Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\Stock\StockItemRepository`

Instead of

`\Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface`

Comment: hi @snkt,it is not working even it is giving some error

Comment: `$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$StockState = $objectManager->get('\Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\Stock\StockItemRepository');
$_productStock  = $StockState->get($_product->getId(), $_product->getStore()->getWebsiteId());
$_productStock->getIsInStock()`

this code working for me in list.phtml

Comment: i tried in list.phtml also but not working.but for me out of stock child products data not coming using \Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\Stock\StockItemRepository                                
i tried with \Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface this one is returning only instock ie 1. can you tell me please this code will read child products stock in list.phtml file.

Comment: Yes,this solution working for configurable and it's child product.i'm use magento 2.2.5